# Find regular respresentation of quaternion group $Q_{8}$.

Tags: group-theory, quaternions

> Find regular respresentation of quaternion group $Q_{8}$.

I am not very familiar with regular respresentations. As far as I know, I need to find all multiplications of elements of group $Q_{8}$ and than observe those multiplications and conclude what element of group $S_{n}$? Is that true? I am beginner in this scope so any hint helps! Thanks.

Comment: The left regular representation of a finite group $G$ means enumerating the elements $g_1,\ldots,g_n,n = |G|$ and defining the matrix $\rho(g)_{ij} = 1$ if $g g_j = g_i$, $\rho(g)_{ij}=0$ otherwise, then $\rho(g)\rho(h) = \rho(gh)$ in $M_n(\Bbb{Z})$. Since $Q_8$ is generated by $i,j$ it suffices to define $\rho(i),\rho(j)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition of the regular representation, the degree of the representation is the group order i.e. $8$. If you want to explicitely find the matrices (over any field $k$), consider the action of the element on each of the other elements in the group.

Concisely, this means (as reuns noted in the comment) 
$$\varrho(g)_{ij} = \begin{cases}
1 & g.g_j = g_i \\
0 & ~ \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

(Again, as reuns noted), it suffices to explicitely compute the $8 \times 8$ matrices for the two generators $i,j$ where $Q_8 := \langle i,j \vert i^4 = 1, i^2 = j^2, jij^{-1} = i^{-1} \rangle$. Then the representing matrices for the other elements of the group can be computed via matrix multiplication.

---

If you are learning representation theory of finite groups and want some explicit examples, have a look at [James & Liebeck](https://books.google.at/books?id=PiJMr6kZP44C&printsec=frontcover&dq=james+liebeck+representation+theory&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjlwqKp5pvkAhXEwKQKHVG1AFAQ6AEILDAA#v=onepage&q=james%20liebeck%20representation%20theory&f=false).

---

Also, if you are aquainted with representation theory via $\mathbb{F}G$-modules, remember that the regular representation is defined as the $\mathbb{F}$-vector space with basis $g_1, \ldots, g_n$ where $\vert G \vert = n$. Then it becomes clear why the coefficients of the representing matrix are determined that way.

Comment: I think you defined the right regular representation. The left-regular is $\rho(g)e_i= e_j$ if $g g_i = g_j$ which means $\rho(g)_{ji} =1$

Comment: @reuns completely right. Thank you